# Python replace path stored on variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, kivy

I'm using Kivy to make a simple APP but i've a trouble with a path.

Explanation:

> 1 - The app has a button to load file from a list ( Filechooser ).
>   [DONE]
>
> 2 - After 'loading' the file the path it is stored into variable and
>   printed as a label. [DONE]
>
> 3 - I need to read and print the data from that file with another
>   button.[FAIL]

Problem:

The output path is like '../../../test.xls' and i can't pass that path to pandas ( i want to read the file with that ) because it has to be './././test.xls'

There's any way to replace the double dots to single dot of that variable string ?

```
def importation(self):
    self.new_label = self.load_label.text
    print self.new_label
    data = pd.read_excel(self.new_label,'Sheet1',index_col=None)
    print data
```

Thanks to everybody.

Comment: `./././test.xls` is the same thing as `test.xls`, you can discard everything but the last part.

Comment: Thanks Norrius i've changed the var from os.path.join(path,filename[0]) to only the filename and it works, guessed the full path was required but it's not, new thing learned, Thank you !